# XSL stylesheet not preserving the encoded values

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have an XML file that i am trying to read & write witin my java program.I am using SAXON 2.0 for this exercise. Below is a sample of the XML file that i have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<actionOverrides>
    <actionName>Accept</actionName>
    <type>Default</type>
</actionOverrides>
<fields>
    <fullName>Dev__c</fullName>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <formula>Sprint__r.Dev_Lead__r.FirstName + &apos; &apos; + Sprint__r.Dev_Lead__r.LastName</formula>
    <formulaTreatBlanksAs>BlankAsZero</formulaTreatBlanksAs>
    <label>Dev Lead</label>
    <required>false</required>
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
    <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
    <type>Text</type>
    <unique>false</unique>
</fields>
<fields>
    <fullName>Manager__c</fullName>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <formula>Sprint__r.Dev_Manager__r.FirstName +&apos; &apos;+  
Sprint__r.Dev_Manager__r.LastName</formula>
    <formulaTreatBlanksAs>BlankAsZero</formulaTreatBlanksAs>
    <label>Dev Manager</label>
    <required>false</required>
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
    <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
    <type>Text</type>
    <unique>false</unique>
</fields>
</CustomObject>
```

What happen is that when i run my data.xsl stylsheet with below code, all of the encoding is replaced with the actual value. In this case  :

```
&apos; &apos;
```

is replace with ' '. What i want is to preserve the encoded values in the file. How can i make that happen ?. Also, the first line  is replaced with . I want to preserve the xmlns value also i the file.

data.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xpath-default-namespace="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"
exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: As far as XML is concerned `&apos;` is identical to `'` and indistinguishable.  Why do you need to preserve the encoding?  If some application downstream can't handle that change, then that app is broken.

Comment: If you want to preserve the original namespaces, then do not remove them. That's what your templates do by renaming the nodes to their local names, instead of just copying them.

Comment: P.S. Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: I am not removing them but the XSL styleshet is removing it. Well we want to preserve those encoding values because when we deploy this XML file, it wants it in the encoded format and then the deployment tool is taking care of decoding etc..

Comment: The XML parser used by the XSLT processor usually will not distinguish between `'` and `&apos;` and simply report the character `'` and of course the XSLT/XPath/XQuery data model also does not store or preserve lexical markup differences. There is a tool LexEv you can run as a pre-processor to XSLT that converts entities into XML markup so your XSLT could then handle them. But as others have said, if the tool dealing with the XML result of the XSLT processor can't handle a character it doesn't know how to parse XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually, an XSLT processor operates on trees of nodes. The input tree of nodes is constructed by an XML parser. It's the job of an XML parser to extract the information content of the XML, and to discard irrelevant distinctions that have no bearing on the information content - such as whitespace between the attributes in a start tag, the difference between single and double quotes around attribute values, the order of attributes, and the distinction between `&quot;` and `"`. The XSLT processor doesn't even know how the XML was written, so it can't preserve such details.

As for the namespaces, when you do `<xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">` you are explicitly copying the local name but not the namespace. If you want to copy both, use `<xsl:copy>`, or `<xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}" namespace="{namespace-url(.)">`.